# error: method setCurrentItemInternal in class

Tags: java, android

When I update my Code to androidx I get this error

```
"error: method setCurrentItemInternal in class ViewPager cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,boolean,boolean,int
found: int,boolean,boolean
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"
```

Code:

```java
    public class NonRestoringViewPager extends ViewPager implements setCurrentItemInternal {
      private boolean isRestoring = false;
      private final boolean useDefaultImplementation;

      public NonRestoringViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        useDefaultImplementation =
            !QuranUtils.isDualPagesInLandscape(context, QuranScreenInfo.getOrMakeInstance(context));
      }

      public NonRestoringViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        useDefaultImplementation =
            !QuranUtils.isDualPagesInLandscape(context, QuranScreenInfo.getOrMakeInstance(context));
      }

      @Override
      public void setCurrentItemInternal(int item, boolean smoothScroll, boolean always) {
        if (useDefaultImplementation || !isRestoring) {
          super.setCurrentItemInternal(item, smoothScroll, always);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void setCurrentItemInternal(int item, boolean smoothScroll, boolean always, int velocity) {
        if (useDefaultImplementation || !isRestoring) {
          super.setCurrentItemInternal(item, smoothScroll, always, velocity);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        isRestoring = true;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        isRestoring = false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
          return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Function signature might have changed in androidx dependencies. So check the function signature and pass required params values.